# How to use a loop inside jquery Fullcalendar events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi i'm trying to loop inside the jquery Fullcalendar events, but i don't know why this is not working :

```
var birthdaysList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.birthdaysList));

$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                lang: 'es',
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prev,next today'
                    //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: //My loop here for title: birthdaysList.name , start birthdaysList.date

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

OK first of all, you can't do a loop inside **envents:** , you have to make an array and then call it from the **envents:** , like this:

```
var birthdaysList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.birthdaysList));

var events = []; //The array
for(var i =0; i < birthdaysList.length; i++) 
{events.push( {title: birthdaysList[i].name , start: birthdaysList[i].date})}


$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                lang: 'es',
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prev,next today'
                    //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: events

            });
        });
```

Comment: You can if you use events function